# Android Studio API level error

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm trying out the new [Android Studio](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html) and it is not recognizing the current API level

[image: Android studio API level error]

My AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.wiproeag.smartbuy"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
    ...
</manifest>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Had this problem too, Android Studio is ignoring the manifest. I changed in in Eclipse.

Comment: Actually it is more annoying rather than actually stopping work. I'm able to build and deploy to the emulator. The app works well on the emulator and device but, Android Studio complains its not right

Answer (score 1):

A possible workaround for this is to include the Android compatibility libraries. Try this one first and get back with the results. I'va also encountered such a problem and it worked for me.

Comment: I already have the `android-support-v4.jar` available in the lib folder.
[Android Studio project structure screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/0MVr5.png)

Comment: Ok, but did you also imported: import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager; Also, taken from the developer.android.com: When creating an activity that hosts fragments while using the Support Library, you must also extend the FragmentActivity class instead of the traditional Activity class.

Comment: Thanks. I'll stick with ADT for now. I was just trying out Android Studio as a possible alternative. I'm sure it will get fixed in the next version :)